# Deep link to a position in a page, using Meteor JS

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor app with multiple pages. I want to be able to deeplink to an anchor somewhere halfway the page.

Traditionally, in normal html, you'd make an  somewhere in your page, and link to it via /mypage.html#chapter5.

If I do this, my meteor app won't scroll down to that spot.

What is the best approach around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using some kind of javascript router? Meteor Router?

You could use something like a javascript based scrolling method. One such example is with JQuery: (You can place this in your link/buttons click handler)

```
Template.hello.events({
  'click #theitemtoclick':function(e,tmpl) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#item_id").offset().top
      }, 600);
   }
});
```

Then tag your html item where you would put your anchor with the id:

```
<h1 id="item_id">Section X</h1>
```

Comment: I am using the backbone router yes. It would be nice this code is executed at page load time, but that I can do. I'll try this, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

@Akshat 's answer works for on the same page, but what if you want to be able to pass around a url w/ a "#" in it? I did it how the meteor docs did.

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
  var hash = document.location.hash.substr(1);
  if (hash && !Template.myTemplate.scrolled) {
  var scroller = function() {
    return $("html, body").stop();
  };

  Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    var elem = $('#'+hash);
    if (elem.length) {
      scroller().scrollTop(elem.offset().top);
      // Guard against scrolling again w/ reactive changes
      Template.myTemplate.scrolled = true;
    }
   }, 
  0);
  }
};

Template.myTemplate.destroyed = function() {
  delete Template.myTemplate.scrolled;
};
```

Stolen from the [source to the meteor docs.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/a3bbb6dfa129b52a909356f2d65f35128a3e6cf5/docs/client/docs.js#L37)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there's an issue in IronRouter where the hash is removed from the url.  This is discussed [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/3) and [here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/315). Fortunately [there is a fix](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/commit/ff274326a8dd75292e69977ae6e32c786d50746e) even though it doesn't appear to be in the  stable version.

My Iron Router solution with traditional anchor tags:

1) Apply the IronRouter fix above

2)

```
Router.configure({
    ...
    after: function () {
        Session.set('hash', this.params.hash);
    },
    ...
});
```

3)

```
function anchorScroll () {
    Deps.autorun(function (){
        var hash =  Session.get('hash');
        if (hash) {
            var offset = $('a[name="'+hash+'"]').offset();
            if (offset){
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: offset.top},400);
            }
        }
        Session.set('hash', '');
    });
}

Template.MYTEMPLATE.rendered = function (){
    anchorScroll();
};
```

Unfortunately this has to be set in each template's `.rendered()` otherwise the anchor tag is not guaranteed to be in the DOM.

For better or worse this will scroll again with a code push.

Answer (score 0):

[Mike's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578639/3700836) didn't quite work for me. The hash was returning empty in the onRendered callback. I nested the code in an additional `Meteor.setTimeout`

fyi I'm using Blaze.

Below worked like a charm :)

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  Meteor.setTimeout(function(){ 
  var hash = document.location.hash.substr(1);
  if (hash && !Template.myTemplate.scrolled) {
  var scroller = function() {
    return $("html, body").stop();
  };

  Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    var elem = $("a[name='" + hash + "']");
    if (elem.length) {
      scroller().scrollTop(elem.offset().top);
      // Guard against scrolling again w/ reactive changes
      Template.myTemplate.scrolled = true;
    }
   }, 
  0);
  }
  },0);
});

Template.myTemplate.destroyed = function() {
  delete Template.myTemplate.scrolled;
};
```